# open multiple webpages in same tab

Tags: javascript, html

Have multiple hyperlinks in a report, everytime a click on a hyperlink the webpage opens in a new tab,
Is it possible to open the hyperlinks in only one tab instead of multiple tabs using javascript ?
Please help

I am currently using window.open to open the webpages, I cannot use  target. Below is the code :

```
    I basically have a jqgrid where all the values of a column have hyperlink,

    if (GridColNum == 2) //index of the column
    {
    localStorage.valuekey = $('#filters_grid').jqGrid('getCell', GridRowId, 1);
    window.open('http://mywebpage.html'); 
    }
```

And i am using the clicked value in another page using localstorage feature

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible.  Use syntax

```
<a href="..." target="rptTab"/>
```

for all relevant links. This way the first time a link is clicked a new tab will be opened; for subsequent clicks, that tab will be reused.

**EDIT:** if you're opening the link in javascript using `window.open`, then you need to specify the name of the tab/window as the second parameter:

```
window.open('http://mywebpage.html', 'rptTab');
```

Comment: @blachawk, [it's in the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-hyperlink-target).

Comment: Just edited my question, sorry for incomplete question pasted

Comment: @zzzzBov the term rptTab is not even on that page.

Comment: @blachawk, if you read the part that I linked to, you'd know that "The target attribute, if present, must be a [valid browsing context name](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#valid-browsing-context-name) or keyword". If you then follow the link for "valid browsing context name", you'd find out that "A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one character that does not start with a `U+005F` LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)"

Comment: Awesome, It works perfectly. 

My understanding now is Each target name associated with anchor tag or passed as an argument from the window.open api gets associated with the opened Tab as an unique name for that Tab. Hence on new URL being opened with the same target name will open on the tab with that target name.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `target='_blank'` attribute in your links. Just remove them. If that does not help please post some code so we can see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the target of a window.open() call or an  tag, you can specify _blank, _parent, _self or _top, as special tab/window names. Alternatively you can specify a new tab/window name, when you specify this tab/window another time, it will refer to the original one that you opened.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. Just use the `target`-attribute of the `a` tag. All links with the same `target` should be opened in the same tab.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

hyperlinks opens a new browser tab - is due to

```
target='_blank'
```

attribute of it. you can remove it using following jQuery code.

```
$('a').removeAttr('target');
```

now on-wards every link will get open in the same page.

Comment: Be careful! There may be other `<a target='specificName`...>` elements in the page!

Comment: yes... here, you can add a class 'sametab', where you don't want to open a new tab. so, $('a .sametab').removeAttr('target'); - will do the required...